# How to exit while loop when key is pressed?

Tags: python, while-loop, pygame, exit

can you pls tell me how to exit a while loop when a key is pressed using pygame and without exiting the whole program? Thanks in advance.
I think the problem is somewhere in the below code:

```
 while True:
    for x in pygame.event.get():
        if x.type == KEYDOWN and x.key == K_ESCAPE:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if x.type == KEYDOWN and x.key == K_UP:
            if playerY > 0:
                playerSpeedY = playerFlyingSpeed
                playerFlying = True
                GAME_SOUNDS["fly"].play()
        if x.key == pygame.K_p:
                pause()

def pause(): 
loop = True
while loop: 
    for x in pygame.event.get(): 
        if x.type == pygame.QUIT:
            loop = False
        if x.type == pygame.KEYDOWN: 
            if x.type == pygame.K_SPACE:
                loop = False
            if x.type == pygame.K_p:
                loop = True
```

Comment: make use of `break` with if block

Comment: I tried it but it gets stuck.

Comment: Can you show us the code ?

Comment: Please post your code, so that we can help you.

Comment: You might want to refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25263766/13850765).

Comment: code is posted, pls tell if you want the whole code

Comment: check this link                                              https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/python-detect-keypress/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your while look needs to be inside the main loop, you enter it by pressing a certain button, and exit it the same way.
You can do that with every screen of your game like this :

```
while True:
    running = True
    while running:
        # Your main loop

    while pause:
        # Your pause menu
```

Here is an example of how I did it with one of my projects :

```
def main():

    # Initialize the pygame modules
    pygame.init()

    # General display settings
    pygame.display.set_caption("McGyver escape")
    SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((32*15, 32*16))
    # Framerate control
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    FPS = 60

    running = True

    # Main game loop
    while running:

        # Initialize the game
        game = Game()

        while game.main_game:
            clock.tick(FPS)

            Player.interaction_check(game)
            interface.screen_update(clock, FPS, SCREEN, game)

            # This loops through all events of the game
            for event in pygame.event.get():

                # Check if we are quitting the game
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    running = False
                    game.main_game = False
                    pygame.quit()

                # Placed here, holding the key will not produce
                # several movements.
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    Player.player_movements(event, game)

        # Lose screen enabled when you encounter a guard and don't have all
        # items
        while game.lose_screen:

            interface.render_lose_screen(clock, SCREEN, FPS)

            for event in pygame.event.get():

                # Check if we are quitting the game
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    running = False
                    game.lose_screen = False

                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    running = False
                    game.lose_screen = False

        # Win screen enabled when getting to the exit
        while game.win_screen:

            interface.render_win_screen(clock, SCREEN, FPS)

            for event in pygame.event.get():

                # Check if we are quitting the game
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    running = False
                    game.win_screen = False

                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    running = False
                    game.win_screen = False

        # Exit the game
        running = False
```